# Circles through two points

Tags: geometry

I'm going through an example from Geometry (Brannan) 2nd ed, involving the following:

Q: Find the equation of the circles that passes through (1,2) and the points of intersection of the circles.

$x^2+y^2-3x+4y-1=0$ and $x^2+y^2+\frac{5}{2}x-3y+\frac{3}{2}=0$.

But a simple check on graphing them on Desmos shows that they don't even intersect. Moreover, the example continues as follows:

Multiply the second circle equation by a scaling factor $k$ and adding it to the first circle equation we get:$\rightarrow x^2+y^2-3x+4y-1+k(x^2+y^2+\frac{5}{2}x-3y+\frac{3}{2})=0$

Since $(1,2)$ must satisfy this equation, it follows that:
$1+4-3+8-1+k(1+4+\frac{5}{2}-6+\frac{3}{2})=0$.

$k$ must equal -3.

Which simplifies to $4x^2+4y^2+21x-26y+11=0$.

But graphing this final equation with the original two circles shows that none of the three circles even intersect each other. Have I gone insane and missed something here?

Answer (score 1):

Is there more to the text of the exercise that what you have included in your question?
The answer given from the textbook suggests that the exercise had a different point.

What you have is two non-intersecting circles and a point $(1,2)$ in the plane lying in the exterior of both circles. Then a unique linear combination of the two circles is found which contains the point $(1,2)$ and which intersects neither of the two circles. It fact it can be inferred that for any point lying in the exterior of both circles such a combination of the two circles can be found.

Here is a link to an [animated Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p7y9zlzgqy) showing what happens when the value of $k$ is allowed to iterate through negative values. The resulting circle sweeps through the entire portion of the plane lying in the exterior of both circles.

Here is a graph when $k=-3$, which is the unique value of $k$ giving a circle containing the point $(1,2)$.
[image: Unique circle containing point]